# pace.js preloader with custom PNG logo animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, preloader

Pace.js ( http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/ ) is a very interesting page preloader. It provides a pace.js file to be simply included and many css themes.

I'm looking for get a custom preloader with PNG / GIF animated logo. Unfortunately, there aren't example about using a custom image instead of text / css3 / circle spinner etc provides by the author.

how would I proceed?
this is the pace CSS code, used to get a simple centered percentage progress.

```
#pagecontent {
    opacity: 0;
}

#pagecontent {
   transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
   -o-transform: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transform: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    transform: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

body.pace-running #pagecontent {
    opacity: 0;
}

body.pace-done #pagecontent {
    opacity: 1;
}  

.pace.pace-inactive {
  display: none;
}

.pace {
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 8888;
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.pace .pace-progress {
  z-index: 8888;  
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}

.pace .pace-progress:before {
  content: attr(data-progress-text);
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  font-family: "BrandonGrotesqueLight", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 20% 0 7px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
}
```

HTML (only page content, where I put the whole site)

```
<div id="pagecontent">
</div>
```